# How to set minimum filesize for mod_deflate?

Tags: .htaccess, compression, mod-deflate

Is there a way in .htaccess to specify a minimum file size that mod_deflate should compress? For example, say I don't want anything below 1K to be compressed. Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear there's any way to set a minimum file size in mod_deflate (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)